# MSSQL Select highest value from grouped results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

This issue is driving me batty.

I have 2 tables:

The first is user_account_log

```
id  username    invoiceid   log_datetime            log_type    log_entry
1   testuser    0       2006-03-30 17:38:14.0000000 Suspend     true 
2   testuser    0       2006-03-30 17:38:30.0000000 Un-Suspend  true 
3   testuser    0       2006-03-31 15:19:42.0000000 Suspend     true 
4   testuser2   0       2006-03-31 17:14:15.0000000 Un-Suspend  true 
5   testuser2   0       2006-03-31 17:15:18.0000000 Suspend     true 
6   testuser3   0       2006-04-06 16:13:59.0000000 Suspend     true
```

and

user_account:

```
username    accountname datestart           dateend
testuser    product1    2000-08-30 23:59:59.0000000 2000-12-29 21:04:33.0000000
testuser2   product2    2000-08-28 14:10:03.0000000 2002-01-21 13:07:05.0000000
testuser3   product1    2000-08-28 16:17:06.0000000 2002-06-30 23:59:59.0000000
```

As part of a larger query - I have a with statement with the following code:

```
SELECT MAX(log_datetime) AS logtime, 
max(id) AS ID,
user_account_log.username, 
ua.accountname,     
log_type,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_account_log.username order by log_datetime) as temp
FROM user_account_log
left outer join user_account ua on ua.username = user_account_log.username
where ua.dateend is null
GROUP BY user_account_log.username, 
log_datetime,
ua.accountname, 
log_type
```

But it's not outputting what I need - the current result set looks like this:

```
logtime             ID  username    accountname     log_type    temp
2011-11-17 15:18:23.0000000 34736   testuser    product1        Un-Suspend  61
2011-11-17 15:18:23.0000000 34736   testuser    product2        Un-Suspend  62
2012-12-10 10:35:08.0000000 35607   testuser    product1        Suspend     63
2012-12-10 10:35:08.0000000 35607   testuser    product2        Suspend     64
2013-09-04 17:09:09.0000000 36587   testuser    product1        Un-Suspend  65
2013-09-04 17:09:09.0000000 36587   testuser    product2        Un-Suspend  66
```

what I need to do is take the most recent log (using either the logtime or ID) - but I need to make sure it's grouped by all products - so the expected result would be limited thus:

```
logtime             ID  username    accountname     log_type    temp
2013-09-04 17:09:09.0000000 36587   testuser    product1        Un-Suspend  65
2013-09-04 17:09:09.0000000 36587   testuser    product2        Un-Suspend  66
```

I'm sure there is something obvious I'm missing in this select - but I've spent the better part of the day with various results, all of which don't look like the result set that I need.

I've also removed any sensitive data - so don't worry that the output differs from the snippet of the table I've included above.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution (although it's not fully written into the main bulk of the script yet) which selected the top ID for each group of rows:

```
select t.*
from (select *,
             max(id) over (partition by username) as max1,
             max(log_datetime) over (partition by username) as max2
      from user_account_log
     ) t
     where t.id = t.max1
```

Thanks to the 2 posters who answered, even though neither was the answer - it helped point me to the right direction

Comment: I think you missed the validation for checking 'where ua.dateend is null' which you have in your initial question.This was the reason why you had LEFT JOIN with user_account.

Comment: Also can you explain me if you only required `MAX(id)` then why did you used partition by on username? In your initial question you mentioned you want `MAX(id)` or `MAX(log_datetime)` grouped by Product(log_type).Even though this might be your answer, this is not the optimized one. You can write it in better way if you have correct table schema.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
select * from 
(SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_account_log.username order by log_datetime) as rn
FROM user_account_log
left outer join user_account ua on ua.username = user_account_log.username
where ua.dateend is null)a where rn=1
```

Comment: That only selects the top row, it doesn't grab the grouped rows - where a user has multiple products, they all get flagged from a single suspend/unsuspend action - so we need to capture  - see the desired output I put in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood your requirements correctly or not but from what you have explained and what I have understood, I guess you can try executing the query after removing "log_datetime" from `GROUP BY` clause and the 'ROW_NUMBER' is not used directly then I think you do not require in this select(In case if you require it then you can always add it). Try to execute below `SELECT` statement if that helps.

```
SELECT
    MAX(log_datetime) AS logtime, 
    MAX(id) AS ID,
    user_account_log.username, 
    ua.accountname,     
    log_type
    --,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_account_log.username order by log_datetime) as temp
FROM user_account_log
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account ua ON ua.username = user_account_log.username
WHERE ua.dateend IS NULL
GROUP BY
    user_account_log.username, 
    --log_datetime,
    ua.accountname, 
    log_type
```

Let me know in case the query doesn't produce expected output.

Comment: Sadly, this produces the same result:

logtime    ID username accountname log_type
2015-06-22 09:00:32.0000000 39146 testuser product1 Suspend
2017-03-01 11:20:52.0000000 41394 testuser product1 Un-Suspend
2010-09-23 01:02:06.0000000 33529 testiser product1 Notice

Comment: Are you sure this produces same results? Because as far as I know SQL from my experience of writing SQL queries since 11-12 years, `GROUP BY` will group by results based on columns you are mentioning into the clause. And remember I did removed `log_datetime` from `GROUP BY` clause you have in your question. So I think there are zero possibility of producing same result if you have same data you given in question.